# Conversion to Dalvik format failed. Issue repeats each time Eclipse is opened

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This problem happens each time I close and reopen Eclipse. It started about a week or so ago. I have not updated Eclipse or the SDKs before this happened.(Not recently)

```
[2013-12-02 19:06:53 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2013-12-02 19:06:53 - com.engel.BillFold] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

The jar "android-support-v4" is being added into my build configuration. It is already in the Private Library that is generated during the build (If android-support-v4 is present.)

I can correct the problem by removing Android 4.3 Library, Private Library (containing android-support-v4) and the intruding extra android-support-v4 jar. Then add Android 4.3 Library and android-support-v4 back in. Reorganize and check off to activate. Clean. Everything will work fine as long as I do not close and restart Eclipse.

One other thing that started about the same time, the debug controls (Disconnect, Terminate, and Suspend) are lit up as if an app is running in debug mode. If you click on Disconnect, I just get an information dialog saying that "*The chosen operation is not enabled*". Just mentioning this part since there may be some connection.

I have read every post I can find on this subject (love SO). I was using the Eclipse bundle from Feb 2013 as downloaded from Android Dev. I just updated to the latest yesterday(Build: v22.3.0-887826), but the problem remains.

One more thought. This started the same day I setup an alarmmanager section in my app. The WakefulBroadcastReceiver is focused on if I do not remove the libraries and extra jar, then replace the offending jars. If I simply remove the extra jar(support-v4) the an error is shown on the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.

```
The import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver cannot be resolved
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE
Ok. So I tried just removing the Android Private Libraries in the build path. This will allow me to send the app to my device. It works fine. Till I close Eclipse and restart it. Then the Private Library is back. Keep in mind that the android-support-v4 is still out in the open, but on restart it is put back into a library by Eclipse. This gives me two of the same jar files. Deleting the exposed jar has no effect. Deleting the Library temporarily fixes the issue.

Damn computers.
Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes.Click on Apply and clean the project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Everything is already checked off. I did try just unchecking the dependencies. That will work. But it is rechecked on restarting. The problem is the additional jar that keeps reappearing. Just don't see why it regenerates.